# Can't find the class com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient (android)

Tags: android, location

I have download a demo project from http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html, and I think I don't lost any steps; But I can't find which jar file contain the “com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient.class” file

We found all "google-play-services.jar" and "maps.jar", and "android.jar (All versions)" 
don't contain the "LocationClient.class"?

Comment: I just update the "extras\google play service" through the "Android SDK Manager", i find the latest "google-play-services.jar" contain the "LocationClient.class" file; (and the old "google-play-services.jar" file just been download 5 days ago)

Answer (score 25):

Add to Gradle file (x.y.z - actual version of Google Play Services):

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:x.y.z'
```

Comment: as of this moment the latest one is: compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'

Answer (score 16):

There is some problem with the last GPS lib. You have to use an older version than the latest(6.+). Try with an older version. I didn't see anything inside the doc deprecated or missing about the `LocationClient.class`.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
```

Comment: This works because in 5.+ the now deprecated LocationClient is still included while in  6.5.+ they have replaced it with a GoogleApiClient, more info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24611977/android-locationclient-class-is-deprecated-but-used-in-documentation

Comment: good answer,but here find the version more actually: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Answer (score 13):

LocationClient is deprecated. You have to use `GoogleApiclient`, like this:

1: Declare a GoogleApiClient variable

```
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
```

2: Instantiate

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mThisActivity)
     .addApi(LocationServices.API)
     .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
     .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
     .build();
```

3: Implement Callback

```
public class YourClass extends BaseFragment implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // your code goes here
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        //your code goes here
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        //your code goes here       
    }
}
```

4: Start to get Location Updates:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

5: Remove Location Updates:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
```

6: Get Last Known Location:

```
private Location mCurrentLocation;

mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

Comment: Thanks, great way for me to rewrite my location-helper class with this new API.

Answer (score 3):

As Location Client is deprecated the class is no more found in the package. We have to use the following instead

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
.addApi(LocationServices.API)
.addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks(){

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
        int priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY;
        if (enableHighAccuracy) {
          priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY;
        }
        request.setPriority(priority);

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationClient, request, new LocationListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                    locationClient.disconnect();
                  }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    })
.addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
})
.build();
```

Answer (score 2):

Jeremie Petitjean's solution worked for me.  Go into `youbuild.grade` file and configure your app for a lower version.  This is what I used and it works now:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'   
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "<APPLICATION NAME>"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2+'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add this to your project `

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'//location services`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update Google Play Service SDK and then use updated library.

Answer (score 1):

check below links

[The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990075/the-import-com-google-android-gms-cannot-be-resolved)

[How to add google-play-services.jar project dependency so my project will run and present map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715716/how-to-add-google-play-services-jar-project-dependency-so-my-project-will-run-an)

Follow these steps and save your time

1. Right Click on your Project Explorer.
2. Select New-> Project -> Android Application Project from Existing Code
3. Browse upto this path only - "C:\Users\**User Name**\Local\Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services"
4. Be careful browse only up to - **google_play_services** and not up to **google_play_services_lib**

And this way you are able to import the google play service lib.
Let me know if you have any queries regarding the same.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of anyone working directly with Phonegap CLI.  In your plugin.xml you require the line

```
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you use Android Studio:

Right click on your app folder -> Open Module Settings -> Dependencies -> Click on the plus button -> Choose library dependency -> Search for "play-services" -> Double click on the com.google.android.gms:play-services

Press Ok and wait for Gradle to rebuild. If error occurs clean and rebuild your project. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164736/android-the-import-com-google-cannot-be-resolved)

Answer (score 0):

Update the Google Play library to the latest version using the Android SDK Manager. In addition, I had to remove the library manually and add it again to my project following [these steps](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html). Version 3.1.36 contains:

[image]

The location folder:

[image]

You might have to update the ADT/SDK as well.