# Cannot import android libraries in android studio

Tags: android, import, libraries

i want to import these libraries but they are giving me an error which says "cannot resolve symbol 'android'". I don't know why i can't import them.

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
```

i want to use GPS/location services in my app and i have the latest android studio version. Does anyone know why am i getting this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android The import com.google cannot be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164736/android-the-import-com-google-cannot-be-resolved)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you missed the first step of [setting up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), which is adding the dependencies to your build.gradle.

For location services, you need the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't set up that Google Play services by adding the dependencies in build.gradle file. Now my code is working fine. Thanks.