# Error package `com.google.android.gms...` doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform, google-maps-android-api-2

I am new to Android development. I am learning to use Parse.com backend service and get stuck early on.

I am following [tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/anywall-android) to create application that uses `Google Maps Android API v2`. What I've done :

1. download [sample
   project](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/AnyWall/zipball/master) from parse
2. Import `AnyWall-android\Anywall` folder from downloaded project to Android Studio
3. Rebuild project

Then I get a bunch of errors here :

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.CancelableCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Circle;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CircleOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
```

`common`, `location`, and `maps` highlighted red. The question is how to resolve these errors?

I appreciate any kind of help or direction (What should I check? Is it about missing library? If it is, what library should I add and where to get it?)

Comment: What does the line in **build.gradle** which import play-services look like?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

[Can't find the class com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636300/cant-find-the-class-com-google-android-gms-location-locationclient-android)

There is some problem with the last GPS lib. You have to use an older version than the latest(6.+). Try with an older version. I didn't see anything inside the doc deprecated or missing about the LocationClient.class...

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'
```

Comment: Oh wow. Had the exact same problem (AnyWall demo too!) and this solved it. Would never have thought about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

I think the best solution is,  add compile API on your Gradle.  **services-location** has this method.

```
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
```

if you wish to include other services, please refer here:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup (scroll down)

Comment: This approach makes more sense since it gives picks only the required dependencies and therefore potentially avoiding dex issues

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 12):

Google Play Services is now modular, you can select the packages you want from it.

To get analytics add:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
```

to you `build.gradle`'s dependencies section

P.S
replace 7.3.0 with new version as they arrive, or replace with "+" to always get the latest

Answer (score 8):

Android Studio is complaining that it can't find the Play Services library.

Follow the steps here to ensure Google Play Services SDK is installed (specifically, make sure 'Google Repository' is installed along with 'Google Play Services'): http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install

Then, make sure the following is added to the `dependencies{}` block in your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Clean and rebuild.

Comment: thanks for reply. You're right, I haven't installed Google Play Services SDK. But I have another problem regarding gradle build system (I'm currently working on this), so I can't check `dependencies{}` and still have the same error.

Answer (score 6):

Add this line you build.gradle in Gradle Scripts folder

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'
    }
```

with this i solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answers were correct.

But in gradle:3.0 the `compile` configuration is now deprecated and should be replaced by `implementation` or `api`.

Check out more information in the documentation - [API and implementation separation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation).

Comment: I ran into this issue and switching `implementation` to `compile` actually solved the issue, but I'm not sure why, if `implementation` is supposed to do the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Its just a common  mistake in my case, I just remove default ""flutter:""  keyword  in pubspec file while managing package