# The import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps

when i update google play service i get this error message:

```
The import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient cannot be resolved
```

and I imported the new google play service and no thing changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's obsoleted, and please use [`GoogleApiClient`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html) instead.

Comment: i get another error The type MainActivity must implement the inherited abstract method 
 GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks.onConnectionSuspended(int)

Answer (score 1):

Although @xizzhu and @Pedro Magalhães are right that `GooglePlayServicesClient` is now deprecated and that `GoogleApliClient` should be used instead, as a quick fix the last version of the `google-play-services_lib` library to include `GooglePlayServicesClient` (version 6.5.87) can be downloaded from https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/google_play_services_6587000_r22.zip.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26838281/2433501) for a full list of links to older versions of the library.

Answer (score 0):

`GooglePlayServicesClient` is deprecated, you must use `GoogleApliClient`.

You can find a better explanation and examples of how to use [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31349335/4208335).