# Can't import an android studio 3.1.1 library

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to import this two Libraries :

import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.DetectedActivity;

but the .android turns to red.
[this what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aIIN.png)

Did i forget to add a package to my project ?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636300/cant-find-the-class-com-google-android-gms-location-locationclient-android

Comment: Yes it worked, Thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in your gradle file :

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'

Check out this : [Can't find the class com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636300/cant-find-the-class-com-google-android-gms-location-locationclient-android)