# This element neither has attached source nor attached Javadoc and hence no Javadoc could be found (for Google Maps)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I've quite searched in stackoverflow and google but I couldn't find a solution. Everytime I hover over an object which comes from the google play services library it gives me the message I have as a title. I mean that I don't have such a problem problem when hovering over "Activity" or "super.onCreate" etc. for exapmle. I have imported the google play services into my project and added the library. I've tried a lot of solutions proposed in here but none helped. Plz be as much specific and thorough as you can be cause I'm still a newbie in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javadocs are those comment blocks you see above code in libraries; they're parsed in a special way such that they can be used, for example, to provide information about a class or method on hover.

The Javadocs for `Activity` and other Android SDK code are provided. But external libraries don't necessarily come with them, or may be provided in a separate jar. Depending on the IDE you're using, the instructions for adding them are different. You can see some instructions for Eclipse by another user, here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17601734/2203712

Comment: You know what man?Tell me where you live so i can send you a THOUSAND OF GOD D#MNED COOKIES. :D

Comment: @user3200294 Your praise is all I need. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hover the object Type and the object's method would give you more information you want.
Hovering to the object itself, will never tell much

Comment: Unfortunately none of them gives me info. Thats what i meant my problem is maybe i didn't express it correctly because english is not my native language.