# Can not get latitude & longitude using onTouchEvent method

Tags: android

I want to get latitude & longitude through the method `onTouchEvent()`.
But it's not working as I expect.
How can I get location using this method.

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity<GeoPoint, OverlayItem> extends MapActivity implements
        GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private LocationManager manager;

    private TextView tvAddress;
    private Button btnSearch;
    private EditText etSearch;
    private LocationClient locationClient;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private MapFragment mapFragment;
    public Bundle mapOverlays;
    MapView mapView;
    GeoPoint p;

     class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
        {
           @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e,
                com.google.android.maps.MapView mapView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

               if(e.getAction()==1){
                   com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
                   Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                          p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," +
                          p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 ,
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }
            return false;
        }
        } 

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        tvAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvaddress);
        btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);
        mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.maps);
        googleMap = mapFragment.getMap();
        locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

    }

    public void onSearch(View v) {

        // Getting user input location
        String location = etSearch.getText().toString();

        if (location != null && !location.equals("")) {
            new GeocoderTask().execute(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        locationClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        locationClient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        try {

            Location currentLocation = locationClient.getLastLocation();
            double lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
            double lng = currentLocation.getLongitude();
            // txtLocation.setText(lat + ", " + lng);

            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

            ArrayList<Address> address = (ArrayList<Address>) geocoder
                    .getFromLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(),
                            currentLocation.getLongitude(), 5);
            Address addr = address.get(0);
            String currentAddress = (addr.getAddressLine(0) + "-"
                    + addr.getAdminArea() + "-" + addr.getLocality() + "-"
                    + addr.getPostalCode() + "-" + addr.getCountryCode());
            MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
            options.position(new LatLng(lat, lng));
            options.title(currentAddress);
            options.snippet("Current location");
            options.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            if (googleMap != null) {
                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(lat, lng), 14.0f));
                googleMap.addMarker(options);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map is null",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    // An AsyncTask class for accessing the GeoCoding Web Service
    private class GeocoderTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Address>> {

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Address> doInBackground(String... locationName) {
            // Creating an instance of Geocoder class
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext());
            ArrayList<Address> addresses = null;

            try {
                // Getting a maximum of 3 Address that matches the input text
                addresses = (ArrayList<Address>) geocoder.getFromLocationName(
                        locationName[0], 3);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return addresses;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Address> addresses) {

            if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Location found",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            // Clears all the existing markers on the map
            googleMap.clear();

            // Adding Markers on Google Map for each matching address
            for (int i = 0; i < addresses.size(); i++) {

                Address address = (Address) addresses.get(i);

                // Creating an instance of GeoPoint, to display in Google Map
                LatLng latLng;
                latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(),
                        address.getLongitude());

                String addressText = String.format(
                        "%s, %s",
                        address.getMaxAddressLineIndex() > 0 ? address
                                .getAddressLine(0) : "", address
                                .getCountryName());
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                // markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                markerOptions.title(addressText);

                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

                // Locate the first location
                if (i == 0)
                    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                            .newLatLng(latLng));
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }







}
```

**Mainfest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mamun.tasktest"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <permission
        android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library  android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>
        <activity

            android:name="com.mamun.tasktest.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
              <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyCgGng3iaqbTxJ3B_lYemZBEqXOonUtFEI" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
       <activity android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >


       </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Its not working only for touch event or and also for click event.

Comment: Have you tried another activity lifecicle moment? I mean, `onCreate` for example

Comment: Not working for anything@Yugesh

Comment: No ..I don't know how to use onTouchEvent() within onCreate...@  MatheusJardimB

Comment: just an fyi, no use of "GeoPoint p;" in your code

Answer (score 0):

> Use this , its works for me

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {    
        GoogleMap map;
        ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



            // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
            SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

            // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
            map = fm.getMap();      

            if(map!=null){

                // Enable MyLocation Button in the Map
                map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);     

                // Setting onclick event listener for the map
                map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                        point.latitude;
                    point.longitude;
                }       
                });
            }       
        }
}
```

> and manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

 <permission
      android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="in.wptrafficanalyzer.locationroutedirectionmapv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="your api key"

        />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"></meta-data>

</application>
```

> also add google-play-service-library as a library project to your
>   project.some important links are given below.

https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw

[How to add google-play-services.jar project dependency so my project will run and present map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715716/how-to-add-google-play-services-jar-project-dependency-so-my-project-will-run-an)

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Install

Comment: Showing error at    semicolon between  point.latitude;(here)point.longitude;

Comment: @user3076959 you can easily get Latitude as double latitute = point.latitude; and Longitude as double longitude = point.longitude; just replace both two lines or initialize values into variables.