# Google Play Service library documentations?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am using Google Play Library versionName="5.0.77-000.

But i am struggling to get Google Play Service library documentation. 
Where can i download Google Play Service library documentation for linking it in my eclipse project?

Answer (score 0):

javadoc you say.  [How to add google-play-services.jar project dependency so my project will run and present map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715716/how-to-add-google-play-services-jar-project-dependency-so-my-project-will-run-an) look down in the answers there exists a coder who has provided alternate instructions for the javadoc.